# Regex Find and Replace: Deleting everything except words starting with "#"?

Tags: regex, keyboard-maestro

I'm a novice at regex and can't find a way to do this easily. I'd like to delete every word that isn't starting with # and put a comma between them, so for example if I have:

```
Cookie Recipe for n00bs
#cookie #recipe #chocolate To do this you have to etc...
Bla bla bla mumbo jumbo
```

I'd like to get as a result:

```
cookie, recipe, chocolate
```

If you could help me it'd be great, thanks and have a good day!

Comment: instead of deleting all the words not preceded with a `#`, why you don't try to match words preceded with a `#`?

Comment: What language/tool do you use?

Comment: I'm trying to use this in a Find and Replace context.I'm creating a Keyboard Maestro Macro which filters the clipboard following this Find and Replace rule. I don't know of a way to only copy the matched Find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to tell which programming language you are using. Here comes an example in PHP, which uses perl compatible regular expressions:

```
$text = <<<EOF
Cookie Recipe for n00bs
#cookie #recipe #chocolate To do this you have to etc...
Bla bla bla mumbo jumbo
EOF;

$pattern = '/((?<=#)\w+)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);

echo implode(', ', $matches[0]);
```

I'm using a so called positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=#)` which ensures that only words are matched which are preceded by a `#` but, and this is important, it does not include the `#` itself into the match. After the lookbehind expression, I'm matching as many word characters `\w` as possible.

After that `implode()` is used to concatenate the resulting matches with a `,`. A regex can't be used for that part of the job.

You can see how this regex works at [Regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/hM6uO2/2)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$re = "/#\\w+/";
$str = "#cookie #recipe #chocolate To do this you have to etc...";
$str .= "#cookie #recipe #chocolate To do this you have to etc...";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$r=@implode(", ",@$matches[0]);  // for adding comma(,) and space( ).
var_dump( $matches,$r);
```

**output:**

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '#cookie' (length=7)
      1 => string '#recipe' (length=7)
      2 => string '#chocolate' (length=10)
      3 => string '#cookie' (length=7)
      4 => string '#recipe' (length=7)
      5 => string '#chocolate' (length=10)

string '#cookie, #recipe, #chocolate, #cookie, #recipe, #chocolate' (length=58)
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/fO2zA0/1)